# Can't ssh into docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm trying to run an [openssh-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openssh-server) container and then connect to it:

```
docker run \
    --name=openssh-server \
    -p 22:22 \
    -e USER_PASSWORD=123 \
    -e USER_NAME=testuser \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    linuxserver/openssh-server
```

```
ssh testuser@localhost
```

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting the error `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **-e PASSWORD_ACCESS=true** in command to allow username/password ssh access and change **-p 22:22 to 22:2222** as container always starts openssh on port 2222 
**Updated command is ::**

```
docker run \
    --name=openssh-server \
    -p 22:2222 \
    -e USER_PASSWORD=123 \
    -e USER_NAME=testuser \
    -e PASSWORD_ACCESS=true \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    linuxserver/openssh-server
```